# Class Not Found error when registering custom widget

Tags: wordpress

So I've been trying to set up a custom widget on WordPress but I've been getting the following error:
`Fatal error: Class 'CustomText_Widget' not found in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 57`

I'm using twentysixteen theme and registering the widget by calling `register_widget` action on `widget_init` in the theme's `functions.php` file this way

```
add_action( 'widgets_init',  function() {
    register_widget('CustomText_Widget');
});
```

The widget class exists in `wp-includes/widgets/` as `customtext-widget.php`. My WordPress version is 4.5.2.

Comment: `wp-includes` is a directory that contains core files for WordPress. You shouldn't place your own files there, it is quite possible that they are removed after an upgrade. Place your files in `wp-content` as a plugin or in your theme and make sure they are loaded.

Comment: How do I do that? Pretty new to WP.

Comment: Start [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).